# How to handle VSTS and TFS during migration from sharepoint 2013 to SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, migration, versioning, tfs

How to handle VSTS and TFS during migration from sharepoint 2013 to SharePoint online. What are the things that need to be setup in SharePoint Online for that and will the versions be preserved while migrating?

Comment: Can you please clarify, if you are you talking about migrating project site collection created when create a project on TFS or TFS code base.

Comment: Yes, I believe that is what he's asking.

Comment: We are migrating Whole SharePoint from 2013 to SharePoint Online. We are using TFS for code related to apps and solution deployment. But as per my understanding TFS is not supported in SharePoint Online. So how to implement the same source control and release management in SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement CI/CD to SharePoint online if you are familiar with PowerShell. Using powershell you can create deployment scripts and Azure DevOps (VSTS/TFS) can execute any powershell task easily.
Following blog series should be really helpful for you in the implementation.

https://sharepointologic.blogspot.com/2017/01/sharepoint-online-continuous-delivery_17.html

https://sharepointologic.blogspot.com/2017/02/sharepoint-online-continuous-delivery.html

https://sharepointologic.blogspot.com/2017/03/sharepoint-online-continuous-delivery.html